# Weapon magazine is zero (infinite ammo or no reload needed?)

Tags: warframe

When looking for weapons in store, I've found one (a bow called Cerno) which Magazine property is set to zero.

Does this mean that it has infinite ammo, or it doesn't need to reload?

Comment: Aside from being a question made 5 years ago (about a game that is subject to change over time), it was asked from the perspective of one relying on credits and waiting hours to complete a weapon whose statistics or mechanics weren't clear for the new player at the time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bows don't really have magazines, so I'd have the answer the question as neither. You load a shot when you hold the mouse button down, and fire the shot when you let it go. It would still have a limited ammo supply.